# Large Data Types for Aerospike python client

Tags: python, aerospike

I am trying to find the Large Data Type support in aerospike for the python client. There is one available for java- would someone know if there's one for python as well?

Comment: Even though the official documentation says that python client supports LDTs (http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/client_matrix.html) but I just can't seem to find an example for the same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at PyPi's hosted documentation:
https://pythonhosted.org/aerospike/llist.html

or (sometimes lagging a version for a few days) the Aerospike website:
http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/llist.html

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Finally got it working by almost following the java client example! :)

Comment: No problem. FYI, work is being done to add the missing functions (filter functions, for example) to the Python client.

Comment: Ronen,
Are these large data types are matured for production use? Or still under experimentation?

Comment: Actually, I suggest that you move to using the atomic list and map operations. Sorted map API was added to the Python client (along with the other language clients) and it'll perform better and be much more stable than LList.   http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.map_set_policy